# How do I get my Eleventy template to not encode HTML tags?

Tags: eleventy

I have an .md file which iterates over a collection of tags:

```
---
title: The First Page
date: Created
tags: 
    - home
    - flashcards
    - info
    - other
---

## {{ title }}

**Publish Date:** {{ page.date }}

This is the index page now.

<ul>
    {% for item in tags %}
    <li>{{ item }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But when I run it (`eleventy --serve`), it encodes the HTML tags:

[image]

**How do I get it to not encode the HTML tags?**

Answer (score 1):

Your tags are being rendered as a code block. Inspect the element and you'll notice that they are rendered as text inside a `<code>` tag, which is subsequently inside a `<pre>` tag.

This is happening because you have indented your `<li>` lines with four spaces, which [markdown-it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/markdown-it) (Eleventy's default markdown parser) treats as a code block, as that is [CommonMark's spec](https://spec.commonmark.org/0.29/#indented-code-blocks).

You have two ways you can solve this. One is to keep your code the same and use a smaller number of spaces for indentation:

```
<ul>
  {% for item in tags %}
  <li>{{ item }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

But this is a markdown file, so you could simplify it further by writing markdown.

```
{% for item in tags %}
- {{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```